# Calculate SD for a given problem specification (see Body) with python

Tags: confidence-interval, python, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I am new here as you can tell.
I have the following problem for which the SD has to be adjusted in order to fit said problem.

---

**Problem:** Say I have 500 balls which I deliver to a customer and if more than 2 of these 500 balls are faulty the whole delivery is returned. Faulty are balls which are not between 38mm to 42mm in diameter. I want to make sure with a 99.9% CI that my delivery does not get returned. How big do I have to set the SD in my manufacturing process to make that happen. (Normally distributed with mean diameter at 40mm) Is the following approach correct or is there an easier way to solve the problem?

---

I used the binomial theorem $P(X) =  \frac{n!}{(n-X)!X!}*p^X*(1-p)^{n-X}$. With $n=500$ and $X=[0,1,2]$, meaning the cases of having 0, 1 and 2 faulty balls. Then added up individual $P(X)$ expressions for the cases 3 cases and let the result be $P(X)_{ALL}$ which should be $1-0.999$ in the present problem. So my unknown is $p$ which is about $0.02225$ according to *WolframAlpha*. (I tried solving for $p$ in Matlab but after 2h of waiting I gave up) Using all the information I have at this point I came up with the following code in python.

```py
confidence_level = 0.999
diameter = 40
n = 500
p = 0.0222515637412984
# p = 0.000381758063307293 #  correct p see Section 'Solved'
q = 1 - p

nd = stats.norm()
SD_factor = nd.ppf(p/2)
SD_calc = 2/np.abs(SD_factor) # 2 since thats the max range 38 to 42mm

my_norm = stats.norm(diameter, SD_calc)
x = np.linspace(35, 45, 500)
y = my_norm.pdf(x)
my_norm_mew = plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

CI_calc = my_norm.interval(confidence_level)
```

To my understanding the CI_calc should be 38 and 42, however it is not. [38.36, 41.64] So where did I go wrong or am I just missing something? Does the 99.9% CI have to be narrower than 38 and 42, and if yes why? I am a newbie in statistics but I want to get better at it and understand what I'm doing, so I would be grateful if you could help me out.

---

### Solved

Let $P(X)_{ALL}$ be 0.999, since the PDF of the binomial distribution at 2 should be: 0.999. Then you calculate $p$ by either using *WolframAlpha* which gives you a numeric solution of $0.00038$ or using root_scalar from scipy.optimize. Both approaches get you the same $p$. Then the same code as in the listing above can be used to calculate the needed SD.

In order to test if this calculated SD is correct I created 10,000, 100,000 and 1,000,000 deliveries of 500 balls each. The number of faulty deliveries were 12, 91 and 1003 respectively.